# Cocoa Touch Framework not loaded for InHouse / Enterprise App

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode6

I have created a framework for our apps. Everything is OK for submitting to store or developing. But when we save it for enterprise, and run on device it crashes because of this;

> Dyld Error Message:
>     Library not loaded: @rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
>     Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/989A855E-50A5-41DF-9D6E-DC57CB91EA6A/MyApplication.app/MyApplication
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/989A855E-50A5-41DF-9D6E-DC57CB91EA6A/MyApplication.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework: mmap() error 1 at address=0x1000E8000, size=0x0005C000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/989A855E-50A5-41DF-9D6E-DC57CB91EA6A/MyApplication.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
>     Dyld Version: 353.12
>
> Binary Images:
>   0x120024000 - 0x12004bfff dyld arm64  <75c68bbe28b13fcd91014f15139742dc> /usr/lib/dyld

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add your framework under 'Link Binary With Libraries' in the Target>Build Phase ?

Comment: Is it copied into your build under the Frameworks group?

Comment: I tried both, but result was same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to revoke your enterprise certificate and create a new one. You'll also need to regenerate your provisioning profiles as well as they will be signed with your existing certificate. Everything works again with a new certificate.

https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/